# Find an exact match from a patterns file for another file using awk (patterns contain regex symbols to be ignored)

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have a file which has the following patterns.

```
NO_MATCH
NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH
NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH
NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH
```

These should be matched exactly with the 5th column of the target csv. I have tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0; next;} NR>FNR{if($5==a[$0])print $0}' pattern.csv input.csv > final_out.csv
```

But the `||`  in the patterns file result in bad matches. The 5th column in the target csv looks something like this:

```
"AAAA||AAAA"
"BBBB||BBBB"
"NO_MATCH"
"NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH||NO_MATCH"
"NO_MATCH||BBBB"
```

I need to extract the 3rd and 4th lines.
Edit: I need exact match such as line 3 & 4. Hope this clears up the issue. The columns in the csv are double quoted as shown, and the quotes around fifth column should be removed.

Comment: Not clear, you saying your 5th column looks like `AAAA||AAAA` etc in target csv? Is it whole file you are talking about only 1 specific column, please be specific in it and do let us know how your target.csv actually look like.

Comment: comma separated, but $5 is `||` separated.

Comment: it will be better if you could add few sample lines for target.csv file, though I have added a solution now but that is  not fully tested since samples are not provided, please add them in your post and let us  know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a["\""$0"\""];next} ($5 in a){gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$5);print}' pattern.csv input.csv > final_out.csv
```

Keep `pattern.csv`'s contents in an array with enclosing each line in quotes. For each line in `input.csv`, if fifth column exists in the array, remove quotes around it and print the line.

Comment: sorry for the comment... typo ...gnuawk BTW.

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail...it works. One last thing, I have added a output file separator as comma as well since the fields were getting separated by space. Please add that and I will accept your answer.